# HTML/PHP Block news tabs on Android and iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I use this code for codebar scan with cellphone, on Google Chrome works but on Firefox and Samsung Browser after scan barcode an another tab are created, and +1 tab per scan.

My code:

```
window.top.location.href = "zxing://scan/?ret=" + href + "profile_sps.php?barid={CODE}";
```

I tried several ways:

```
window.open("zxing://scan/?ret=http://rodrigovrodrigues.tk/sjb/profile_sps.php?barid={CODE}", "_top");

window.self.location.href = "zxing://scan/?ret=" + href + "profile_sps.php?barid={CODE}";

window.parent.location.href = "zxing://scan/?ret=" + href + "profile_sps.php?barid={CODE}";
```

And some others...

Any friend can help me with this?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Why do you need to use `top` and not `self`? Like `window.location.href = "..." `?

Comment: I tried window.location.href = "..." but also dont work.